# What is '@!' file?

Tags: files, vi

I have a filename `@!` in my home folder. When I open it, it has the same content that my other bash file `myscript.sh` has.

I have not assign execute permission to original bash file. When I have checked properties, the only difference between two file is size. Original file size is 1.1 KB and `@!` file size is 714 bytes. How is it automatically created?

Comment: Does it get recreated if you delete, rename or move it?

Comment: @Videonauth I've not done task of either delete, rename or remove.

Comment: Which other bash file? Have you checked your command history for `@!`?

Comment: Could it be the side-result of some buggy bash code you ran?

Comment: @muru other bash file means? Like which command for `@!` ? any file creation?

Comment: @M.Becerra Possibly

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you use Vim, this could be because you typed `:w@!` instead of `:wq!`. On the US layout, `@` is on <kbd>2</kbd>, directly above <kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, and right next to `!` on <kbd>1</kbd>. Easy to mistype.

You can verify this by running Vim again, and examining the command history by either scrolling up using the up arrow key in command mode, or typing [`q:` in normal mode](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q%3A).

Comment: Well, I do have a bunch of files named `cat` lying here and there because I typed `:'<,'>w! cat` instead of `:'<,'>w !cat`.

Comment: I've again checked the content of both file again. Size difference is because the original file content is bit modified after mistakenly created `@!` file. So indeed this should be accepted answer.

Comment: @muru you should erase your identity and go work as a secret detective. Wow...

Comment: As a Vim noob, why would you combine `!` with `w`? Try to save a maybe-read-only file but quit anyways?

Comment: @NickT : Maybe because people are often just taught that "q!" means quit without asking questions, and inserting a w before that will write.  (Technically you should ask such a question as a separate question, but I figured that might be downvoted/closed as a not-researched-well-enough question.)

Comment: @NickT If you own a file with mode 05??, it will be "read only", even to you. But vim knows that you own it and you can force it with `:w!`.

Comment: and here is my command line history : `:wq`, `:wq@!`, `:.!:q!`,`:w@!`, `:wq!`, `:q!`